# How to get bootstrap select picker click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap select picker in which I want the event on click of
dropdown, because after that, I want to append some dynamic option through
ajax so I want to show alert when user will click the dropdown. I have
tried below code but it is not working.

Html

```
<select id="new2">                                                              
   <option>Select Vendor</option>                                                         
</select>
```

Script code

```
$("select").on("click", function() {
  alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 10):

This is the real solution for bootstrap selects to handle click event:

```
$('#new2').on('show.bs.select', function() {
    //some code...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `onchange()` function for select box:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
   alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: but i want event on click of dropdown using onchange will give me event on click of options.I want click event on dropwdown because i want to generate dynamic option list for user.

Comment: @varunjoshi If you already have a working example, why ask it here again?

Comment: Just replace `change` to `click` @varunjoshi

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event for `select`.

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
  alert("hello");
});
```

Alternatively you can do.

```
$("select").change(function() {
  alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an onchange function if you want to catch a select function

```
 $("select").on("change", function() {
     alert("hello");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class for this.

```
$(".filter-option").on("click", function() {
  alert("hello");
});
```

[WorkingFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/v7naao59/134/)

Comment: hi this code is right but don't know why it is not working with my end may be i have multiple dropdown on my page so is there any option to target particular select box

Comment: Multiple drop down doesn't gives any problem. See this updated fiddle.`http://jsfiddle.net/shree/v7naao59/135/` . I think loading jquery and bootstrap gives you conflict and code not work.Some one is load twice.

Comment: yes your fiddle code is working fine but dont know why it is not working with my end i have only taken you script code  and html is there any other thing you are doing to removing confliction.

Comment: no there is no error in the console can you share your email id i will send you the html code file.

Comment: or is there any traversing option through which we can reach to the particular select box.

Comment: Its impossible to say without see your HTML. Post your html on fiddle .Sorry I can not give my email publicly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164167/discussion-between-varun-joshi-and-shree-khanal).

Answer (score 0):

### you can do

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
      alert("hello");
    });
```

### and if you want click event on drop down then you already have an id

```
$("#new2").on("click", function() {
          alert("hello");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use this event in the bootstrap-select lib.

```
$('#mySelect').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
  // do something...
});
```

Thanks!